# Memory leak in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, memory-leaks

I configured a new Web server. Now I'm restoring old websites from backups. For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
[Sat Aug 09 04:10:49 2014] [warn] [client X.X.X.X] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /var/www/clients/client3/web3/web/libraries/joomla/error/exception.php on line 117
```

Line 117:

```
$this->backtrace = debug_backtrace();
```

It's clear for me that there is some memory leak in the index.php. It is not my website so I can't really change anything in that script. However it worked on the old server. Anyone has an idea of what's causing it? I already increased the memory_limit in php.ini.

Here's the script (index.php):

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark( 'afterLoad' ) : null;
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
$mainframe->route();
$Itemid = JRequest::getInt( 'Itemid');
$mainframe->authorize($Itemid);
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterRoute');
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$mainframe->dispatch($option);
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null;
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterDispatch');
$mainframe->render();
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null;
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterRender');
echo JResponse::toString($mainframe->getCfg('gzip'));
```

In my opinion the getApplication() function is somehow causing the memory leak.
phpinfo() result: http://pastebin.com/GEtqfWsK

Comment: The only thing we know is that the script is using too much memory. It is usually because of infinite loops/recursion, but it could be anything. We need to know more in order to answer your question.

Comment: @xtraorange $this->backtrace = debug_backtrace();

Comment: Please show phpinfo() function output here.

Comment: Ah, a more awake version of myself would have looked at the file name and realized that line number was going to be useless.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Pvb http://pastebin.com/GEtqfWsK

Comment: Try to reduce memory_limit parameter in php.ini

Comment: I reduced it to 64M. Still nothing. I also tried to comment out the line 117. It resulted in an "Internal Server Error". But after reducing the memory_limit I'm just getting a blank, white page just like before.

Comment: I seen the same problem when i moved from one hosting to another. The problem was because there were some big images and one of joomla modules try to resize and get memory out bounce problem. Maybe in your case you had cleared cache folder and joomla try to cache some image files resizing some big images.

Comment: @Pvb I think that you're right. There are tons of images with huge resolution. But how can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you have a cache folder from previous hosting just copy it to a new hosting.

Comment: @Pvb Unfortunately my cache folder is empty and I haven't got the old one. Is there any way to resize those images without consuming so much memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59000/discussion-between-pvb-and-user3125731).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept getting this error when I moved my website (Joomla based) from old server to the new one. Suggestions about memory_limit didn't helped me.
Problem was solved when I have changed $cache_handler from 'memcache' to 'file' in configuration.php (Joomla root directory).